# GUI class using functions before class creation

Tags: python, function, class, user-interface, tkinter

So i'm a real newb at Python and need a bit of help/advice on how to solve this small problem i have.

Im trying to create a Python Application in which people can chat which each other and use Tkinter for it's User interface.

And im trying to bind a function, that is from a class that hasn't been created yet, to a tkinter element.

Here is the class for the Client:

```
class Client(object):

    def __init__(self, gui):
        self.gui = gui
        self.socket = socket.socket()
        self.ip = 0
        self.onserver = False
        self.adressabfrage()
        self.verbindungsaufbau()
        while self.onserver == True:
            self.s()
            self.r()
    def adressabfrage(self):    
        self.ip = input('IP Adresse des Servers:')
        self.portstring = input('Port des Servers:')
        self.port = int(self.portstring)

    def verbindungsaufbau(self):        
        self.socket.connect((self.ip, self.port))
        self.onserver = True

    def s(self, event=None):
        self.nachricht = gui.meine_nachricht.get()
        gui.meine_nachricht.set("")
        self.socket.send(bytes(self.nachricht, 'utf-8'))
        if self.nachricht == "{quit}":
            self.socket.close()

    def r(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.ze = self.socket.recv(1024)
                self.data = self.ze.decode('utf-8')
                gui.nachrichten_liste.insert(tkinter.END, self.data)
            except OSError:
                break


    def end(self):
        self.socket.close()
```

And I import the GUI which is here:

```
class GUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = tkinter.Tk()
        self.top.title("Client")
        self.nachrichten_fenster = tkinter.Frame(self.top)
        self.meine_nachricht = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.meine_nachricht.set("Hier Nachricht eingeben.")
        self.scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.nachrichten_fenster)
        self.nachrichten_liste = tkinter.Listbox(self.nachrichten_fenster, height=15, width=50, yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
        self.nachrichten_liste.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
        self.nachrichten_liste.pack()
        self.nachrichten_fenster.pack()
        self.eingabe_feld = tkinter.Entry(self.top, textvariable=self.meine_nachricht)
        self.eingabe_feld.bind("<Return>", client.s)
        self.eingabe_feld.pack()
        self.senden_knopf = tkinter.Button(self.top, text="Senden", command=client.s)
        self.senden_knopf.pack()
```

The problem is, i have to create the GUI class first, and when i try to, it prompts me with this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\prime\Desktop\Client    \client(2) - Copy.py", line 67, in <module>
gui = GUI()
File "C:\Users\prime\Desktop\Client\client(2) - Copy.py", line 60, in __init__
self.eingabe_feld.bind("<Return>", client.s)
NameError: name 'client' is not defined
```

I'm aware that my code may be horribly organized, and that I haven't stuck to the rules of basic python coding probably.

But I hope somebody can help me out here.

Btw the issue is in the gui code 4th from botton.

Comment: Well, what does `client` refer to in this line?

Comment: i created the Client as: client = Client() and client.s is the function s in client

Comment: It looks like you constructed `GUI` before defining `client`, so this name doesn't exist at the time of initializing GUI.

Comment: Yeah i'm aware of that, but if i'd initialize Client before the GUI i would get problems with the Client Class telling me that the gui doesn't exist yet

Comment: Why would `Client` care about `GUI` anyway? That doesn't make much sense to me because their logic can safely be separated. You can implement the logic of the client without any GUI at all and then create the GUI that would have an instance of Client and call its methods accordingly.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, i'm gonna rewrite and see if i'm able to do it the way you said.